# Is there a way to build Dynamic Linq Queries in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, linq, runtime, dynamic

1). I tried to Use `ObjectQuery` but doen't work in Silverlight

2). I tried to follow this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx this too didn't work for me in Silverlight

so is there any way i can use,

```
var ase = a.Select("NEW(activity_date as date)");
```

in silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the post and comments [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2009/10/10/using-dynamic-linq-in-silverlight-projects.aspx) outline modifications that can be made to Dynamics.cs to allow it to build for SL Projects.

Comment: it compiles well but executing it in the browser it raises an exception in xaploader which is wired

Comment: May want to add details about the exception to your question.